# File uploads not working, but dosen't pull up an error

Tags: python, python-2.7

First things first:
 - I'm using Python 2.7.7 because cPanel is broken.
 - This is a blog thing I am making for a challenge

What I'm trying to do is, upload a file in the field `p_image` and save it in `assets/images/post_images/` and name it `p_title + original file name` (`p_title` is the name of the post).
This is my code currently.

```
filedata = data['p_image']
if filedata.file:
    with file(data.getvalue("p_title"), 'w') as outfile:
        outfile.write(filedata.file.read())
        post = "Success"

#start code stuff such as Content-type html \r\n\r\n don't worry it's the file upload not the print script   
print post
```

This is the html script;

```
<div class="create_post">
                <form method="GET" action="post_blog.py" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <input type="text" name="p_auth" placeholder="Enter Post Authenticator" />
                    <h2>Post preview</h2>
                    <input type="file" name="p_image"><br/>
                    <input type="text" name="p_title" placeholder="Title your post" /><br/>
                    <input type="text" name="p_date" placeholder="Date" /><br/>
                    <h1>Inside</h1>
                    <p>Title, date & preview image are to be placed here!<p>
                    <input type="text" name="p_desc" placeholder="Post Description" /><br/>
                    <input type="submit" value="Post!">
                </form>
            </div>
```

I am quite confused why it won't copy the file into my dir. Because it never pulls up an error it just dosen't save it.

## EDIT:

```
filedata = data['p_image']
post = str(filedata) + "\n"
    if filedata.file:
        with file(data.getvalue("p_image"), 'w') as outfile:
            outfile.write(filedata.file.read())
            post += "Success"
```

This gives me this error,

```
<type 'exceptions.TypeError'>   Python 2.6.6: /usr/bin/python
Wed Jul 25 21:08:33 2018

A problem occurred in a Python script. Here is the sequence of function calls leading up to the error, in the order they occurred.
 /home/bearncat/*removed link due to privacy*/post_blog.py in ()
   39         post = str(filedata) + "\n"
   40         if filedata.file:
   41             with file(data.getvalue("p_image"), 'w') as outfile:
   42                 outfile.write(filedata.file.read())
   43                 post += "Success"
builtin file = <type 'file'>, data = FieldStorage(None, None, [FieldStorage('p_auth',..., ''), FieldStorage('p_desc_image_1', None, '')]), data.getvalue = <bound method FieldStorage.getvalue of FieldStor... ''), FieldStorage('p_desc_image_1', None, '')])>, outfile undefined

<type 'exceptions.TypeError'>: file() argument 1 must be encoded string without NULL bytes, not str
      args = ('file() argument 1 must be encoded string without NULL bytes, not str',)
      message = 'file() argument 1 must be encoded string without NULL bytes, not str'
```

I also did update the html to:

```
<form method="POST" action="post_blog.py" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

## PROBLEM SOLVED!!!!!

```
filedata = data['p_image']
p_filename = str(data.getvalue("p_title"))
p_filename += os.path.basename(filedata.filename)
if filedata.file:
    with file(p_filename, 'w') as outfile:
        outfile.write(filedata.file.read())
        post += "Success"
```

Comment: Did you check if the data['p_image'] itself does contain data? It would help if you post your code for post_blog.py. Also, is the form method really a get? you can't pass file data if it's a get.

Comment: So, `data[p_image]` does contain `.png` like content. I changed the form to POST but now, it's giving me a TypeError.

Comment: @FranreySaycon Full code pastebin at: https://pastebin.com/bPZsqsm4. HTML code at: https://pastebin.com/qds60BW0. Quick edit, the python code works if I don't have `data.getvalue()`in the filename, it works.

Comment: data.getValue("p_image") might have a null character \0. this is a very common error.

Comment: @FranreySaycon how do I remove them without corrupting the file?